# jConfirm is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, confirm, jconfirm

I have a simple script that prompts the user to confirm delete, then it just alerts them that the process was completed properly.

I tried using jConfirm and the Javascript console spits out:
"ReferenceError: jConfirm is not defined"

```
<!-- jConfirm --> 
// the script is referenced properly    
<script src="/js/jconfirm/jquery.jconfirm-1.0.min.js"></script>


<script>
function careersDelete(career_id) {
  jConfirm('Are you sure you want to delete this career?', 'Delete Career', function (x) {
    if (x) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "ajax_career_delete.php",
            type: "GET",
            data: "career_id=" + career_id,
            success: function (response) {
                alert('Career deleted');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

}

On the button that should enable the confirm dialog, I have:

```
<a href="#" onclick="careersDelete('<?php echo $career_id; ?>')">delete</a>
```

Comment: are `jQuery` and `jConfirm` libraries correctly included?

Comment: Yeah they are both loaded properly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check out [these examples](http://riggerthegeek.github.io/jConfirm/examples.html) you'll see that you need to separately source jquery, and that jconfirm is only defined within its namespace. Thus you need to add two things in your code:

```
<script src="/js/jquery.js"></script> <!-- or wherever jquery.js's path is -->
...
  $.jconfirm('Are you sure  ...
  // note jquery's $. namespace; and the non-capitalized "c" in jconfirm
```

---

Additionally, the `$.jconfirm` function call is not expecting strings. It signature is:

```
function(options, callback)
```

And the `callback` is not executed with any parameters (thus your `x` will be `undefined`). It looks like what you wanted was somewhere along the lines of:

```
function careersDelete(career_id) {
  jQuery.jconfirm({
       message: 'Are you sure you want to delete this career?',
       title: 'Delete Career'
  }, function () {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "ajax_career_delete.php",
            type: "GET",
            data: "career_id=" + career_id,
            success: function (response) {
                alert('Career deleted');
            }
        })
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi blgt thanks for helping out it says that TypeError: $.jconfirm is not a function.

Comment: Hurray that did it! Thanks a lot and for explaining it rather than just giving an answer. I have to go back to the drawing board with JS, because there are some concepts I don't think I'm fully understanding. Thanks again.

Comment: @Hugo Then you're not loading them properly. Make sure they're loaded in this order: http://jsfiddle.net/P66XF/ (fiddle should log a function type) Edit: oh well nevermind that then. Fiddle should still be a concept